vue3+vite5: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"
Please ask a question about vite packaging. I made a project with springboot3 + vue3 + vite5. The local operation is normal, but I encountered a problem when packaging. That is, after packaging, there are only a few files in the dist folder. Is it normal? In addition, the following problems have arisen. I do not know why?
After packaging and putting it on the server, the home page (login page) can be accessed, but after entering the user name and password, Click login, and the following error appears:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost/views/index.vue
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost/views/index.vue

Packaging Method 1: The results of the packaging command are as follows
> vite build
 
vite v5.3.5 building for production...
✓ 1571 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                      0.48 kB │ gzip:   0.32 kB
dist/assets/bgimg-DjLelNA2.jpeg  7,784.52 kB
dist/assets/index-Dw9PIufV.css     324.93 kB │ gzip:  44.90 kB
dist/assets/index-BGWgzp1d.js      628.88 kB │ gzip: 213.56 kB
 
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
✓ built in 3.77s


Packaging Method 2: I add the following configuration to vite.config.js:
build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        // 分包
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return id
              .toString()
              .split("node_modules/")[1]
              .split("/")[0]
              .toString();
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }

This time, more files have been packaged. The results of the packaging command are as follows:
> vite build
 
vite v5.3.5 building for production...
✓ 1571 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "@floating-ui".
Generated an empty chunk: "dayjs".
Generated an empty chunk: "lodash-unified".
Generated an empty chunk: "memoize-one".
Generated an empty chunk: "normalize-wheel-es".
Generated an empty chunk: "vue".
dist/index.html                                          1.54 kB │ gzip:  0.54 kB
dist/assets/bgimg-DjLelNA2.jpeg                      7,784.52 kB
dist/assets/index-_rFj-IOj.css                           1.60 kB │ gzip:  0.51 kB
dist/assets/element-plus-BJZDLfJd.css                  323.34 kB │ gzip: 44.55 kB
dist/assets/dayjs-l0sNRNKZ.js                            0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/vue-l0sNRNKZ.js                              0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/@floating-ui-l0sNRNKZ.js                     0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/normalize-wheel-es-l0sNRNKZ.js               0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/lodash-unified-l0sNRNKZ.js                   0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/memoize-one-l0sNRNKZ.js                      0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
dist/assets/pinia-plugin-persistedstate-RV7uh3T-.js      1.94 kB │ gzip:  0.90 kB
dist/assets/pinia-CXYsz0yr.js                            3.84 kB │ gzip:  1.97 kB
dist/assets/@vueuse-DFh7vuZN.js                          6.08 kB │ gzip:  2.64 kB
dist/assets/@ctrl-r5W6hzzQ.js                           14.13 kB │ gzip:  4.76 kB
dist/assets/async-validator-DKvM95Vc.js                 16.90 kB │ gzip:  5.41 kB
dist/assets/@popperjs-D9SI2xQl.js                       19.77 kB │ gzip:  7.37 kB
dist/assets/lodash-es-CbX0-HeL.js                       22.01 kB │ gzip:  7.80 kB
dist/assets/vue-router-DyUJW7uH.js                      23.12 kB │ gzip:  9.48 kB
dist/assets/axios-DTyqpfTh.js                           34.60 kB │ gzip: 13.93 kB
dist/assets/@vue-5jp81eLw.js                            70.09 kB │ gzip: 27.98 kB
dist/assets/index-lL5Sh4cQ.js                          104.57 kB │ gzip: 41.58 kB
dist/assets/element-plus-BKnJWsug.js                   140.07 kB │ gzip: 47.39 kB
dist/assets/@element-plus-C7iXwfg3.js                  172.90 kB │ gzip: 44.58 kB
✓ built in 3.70s



Packaging seems ok, the problem seems to be connected with what happens when you press the login button. Consider adding that code to the question.
